# Consistency across Data for group level

Tags: multilevel-analysis, group-differences, intraclass-correlation

I want to design a MLM model that shows there is inconsistency in Y variable on group level. Any ideas on how to do that? When I add more predictors, the ICC goes up. But I need to demonstrate that there is meaningful difference across groups (I know for a fact that each group's data comes from a different data source, then aggregated on a shared level that we are defining as the level 1). My point is to show that the inconsistencies in original data sets are the cause of the variance. Please guide me into figuring out how to do that.

Here's my mlm:

RegionalProgress = β0j + β1j * Demographics + u0j + e0ij

As I said, the regional data is a combination of data from a few cities. The RegionalProgress was calculated at level 1 (neighborhood level) and the demographics were added for level 1 as well. So my model in code looks like this:

model11 <- lmerTest::lmer(RegionalProgress ~ 1 + (1|CITY) + PopDen + HomeOwn + Income + Black + Asian + Hispanic + Age, data = data, REML = FALSE)

The point of the analysis is to prove or reject that since this "RegionalProgress" is not consistent enough because it is coming from data sets with various and different data characteristics. So I want to be able to show:

1. there are meaningful differences (or not) between the data sets across cities,
2. how these differences do affect multivariate relationships?

Comment: This is so vague as to appear unanswerable.  Could you provide some details and definitions?  In particular, what is an "inconsistency," what role does a "Y variable" play in an "MLM," and exactly what is your MLM?

Comment: Sure. Just updated my question. Would appreciate any help!